# Springboot jar as window service

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, procrun

I am trying to run springboot jar as window service and i was able to do using below script.
It generates two process prunsrv.exe and java.exe.
But on stopping the service it only stops prunsrv.exe(using //SS//Myservice) but i can see java.exe process still running which i have to end using task manager only.
How to stop both the process at a time such that i dont have to search processin taskmanager to kill?

```
set "CLASSPATH=D:\temp-1.0.0.jar"

prunsrv.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --Description "Myservice" ^
    --DisplayName "%DISPLAYNAME%" ^
    --Install "%EXECUTABLE%" ^
    --LogPath "D:\MyService" ^
    --Startup auto ^
    --StdOutput auto ^
    --StdError auto ^
    --Classpath "%CLASSPATH%" ^
    --Jvm "%JVM%" ^
    --StartImage "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" ^
    --StartMethod start ^
    --StopMethod stop ^
    --StartMode exe ^
    --StopMode java ^
    --StartPath "D:\MyService" ^
    --StopPath "D:\MyService" ^
    --StartClass com.darth.MyService ^
    --StopClass com.darth.MyService ^
    --StartParams -jar#%CLASSPATH% ^
    --StopParams stop ^
    --JvmMs 1024 ^
    --JvmMx 6144
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Procrun in `Java` mode almost certainly will not work:

> When using the **Java** or **exe** modes, the Procrun service application (prunsrv) launches the target application in a separate process. The "stop" application needs to communicate somehow with the "start" application to tell it to stop. For example, using RPC.

(source [Procrun documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html#Using_Procrun_in_Java_or_exe_mode)).

The easiest way to stop your service is to use the **jvm** mode, in which case Procrun starts the JVM itself and can call an arbitrary static method with parameters `String[]` inside the same JVM to shut it down. E.g. your can modify your application like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyService extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command = "start";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            command = args[args.length - 1];
        }
        switch (command) {
            case "start":
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
                break;
            case "stop":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

}
```

and install it like this:

```
prunsrv.exe //IS//MyService ^
    --Description "MyService" ^
    --Startup auto ^
    --Classpath "D:\temp-1.0.0.jar" ^
    --StartMode jvm ^
    --StartClass org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ^
    --StopMode jvm ^
    --StopClass org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ^
    --StopParams stop ^
    --LogPath "D:\MyService" ^
    --LogLevel Debug ^
    --StdOutput auto ^
    --StdError auto
```

### Alternative solution

An undocumented feature of Procrun (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/49c6a4ac10b2760270468eac73043e1b0a94b7d7/src/native/windows/src/javajni.c#L958)) allows to call `System.exit(0)` directly **without any modification** to the application. You just need to set the stop class to `java.lang.System`:

```
prunsrv.exe //IS//MyService ^
    --Description "MyService" ^
    --Startup auto ^
    --Classpath "D:\temp-1.0.0.jar" ^
    --StartMode jvm ^
    --StartClass org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ^
    --StopMode jvm ^
    --StopClass java.lang.System ^
    --LogPath "D:\MyService" ^
    --LogLevel Debug ^
    --StdOutput auto ^
    --StdError auto
```

Comment: P.Karwasz I tried you script . The service is not even starting now. It gets installed and then shows service error code 4 on starting. On checking system event logs it shows that "The system cannot open the file".

Comment: The class I previously gave in the answer should be replaced with `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`. If other errors occurs, run `prunmgr //ES/MyService` and try setting the path to `jvm.dll` manually.